# join two tables to display data

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin

i have tried to join two tables. one is category and other is subcategory. id in category table becomes the cat id in subcategory table

category

```
id  name  catimage  
2   cat1  image1
```

subcategory

```
id  name     subcatimage  catid
1   subcat1   image2       2
```

the code is

```
<?php
ob_start();
require_once('config.php');

    $selectsubcategory = mysql_query("SELECT category.name, subcategory.name, category.catimage, subcategory.id, subcategory.catid FROM category INNER JOIN subcategory ON category.id=subcategory.catid ");    
    $posts = array();
    if(mysql_num_rows($selectsubcategory)) 
        {
            while($post = mysql_fetch_assoc($selectsubcategory)) 
                {
                    $posts[] = $post;
                }
            header('Content-type: application/json');
            echo stripslashes(json_encode(array('subcategorylist'=>$posts)));
        } 
    else 
        {
            header('Content-type: application/json');
            echo stripslashes(json_encode(array('subcategorylist'=>'No subcategory')));
        }
?>
```

I am getting all the details but the problem is that i am not getting category.name in result. can anyone help

P.S i have used sql, will change it later right now my concern is the functionality part

Comment: create alias and check `"SELECT category.name as catname, subcategory.name as subcatname, category.catimage, subcategory.id, subcategory.catid FROM category INNER JOIN subcategory ON category.id=subcategory.catid "`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The subcategory.name overrides your category name.
You have to use an alias for your subcategory name like that:

```
 $selectsubcategory = mysql_query("SELECT category.name, subcategory.name AS sub_name, category.catimage, subcategory.id, subcategory.catid FROM category INNER JOIN subcategory ON category.id=subcategory.catid ");
```

Answer (score 1):

may this will help you...

here **MainCatName** will display category name field data... and
**SubCatName** will display as a subcategory name field data...

```
SELECT
    `category`.`name`  AS MainCatName
    , `subcategory`.`name` AS SubCatName
FROM
    `category`
    INNER JOIN `subcategory` 
        ON (`category`.`id` = `subcategory`.`catid`);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
      Category.name, category.catimage,
      subcategory.name, subcategory.id,
      subcategory.catid
FROM
     category INNER JOIN subcategory
WHERE
      category.id = subcategory.catid
```